Need help in Power Automate Flow
I am creating a Power automate flow where I want a unique email based on the excel data. My data structure look like Email ID Column, first cell having two email IDs abc@gmail.com, xyz@gmail.com, second cell again abc@gmail.com, third cell asd@gmail.com
Email ID

abc@gmail.com, xyz@gmail.com
abc@gmail.com
asd@gmail.com

based on above three's a 3 unique email ID. How to get the same result using power automate flow?
I created the flow with When a file is created, used a Union expression "union(body('Select'),body('Select'))
